# getting compile time error while converting string to set?

Tags: python, set

I'am getting error in the last assert statement but i don't no why please help me

```
def test_set_creation():
    """
    sets can be created from any sequence like list or a tuple.
    """
    test_list = [1, 2, 1, 3]
    set1 = set(test_list)
    assert {1,2,3} == set1

    test_string = "apple"
    set2 = set(test_string)
    assert {} == set2
```

Comment: You are not getting a 'compile time error' here. You would, at best, get a assertion exception.

Answer (score 3):

`{}` creates an empty *dictionary*, not an empty set. Your assertion will always fail.

Use `set()` to create an empty set object, and you probably should test that `set2` is *not* empty:

```
assert set() != set2
```

From the [set displays reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#set-displays):

> A set display is denoted by curly braces and distinguishable from dictionary displays by the lack of colons separating keys and values
>
> [...]
>
> An empty set cannot be constructed with {}; this literal constructs an empty dictionary.

Comment: is there any condition in the place of assert ____ == set2

Comment: @TirupatiRao: what do you expect to assert here? You failed to mention that in your question; what should the code *do*.

Answer (score 1):

You are asserting dictionary and set which is wrong in the last line.

```
>>> type({})
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(set())
<type 'set'>
>>>
```